# Rails won't install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

To start I'm pretty new at rails which I'm sure this question will show. I was about to follow the steps on gorails.com to setup a local server. I also use codeanywhere for when I have internet access. When I try to install (rails new myapp) rails I keep getting the following error from my terminal command

```
extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/var/folders/0d/yx9wdh954jjbn_pnn5nbm5540000gn/T/bundler20190310-64475-5t7xkksqlite3-1.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0
for inspection.
Results logged to
/var/folders/0d/yx9wdh954jjbn_pnn5nbm5540000gn/T/bundler20190310-64475-5t7xkksqlite3-1.4.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
Could not find gem 'uglifier (>= 1.3.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems."
```

Any Help on the matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to run `bundle install` as suggested in the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please edit the file in your ruby rails project named `Gemfile` and change following

```
gem  'sqlite3'
```

to

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.11'
```

Now run following command to install Gem

```
bundle install
```

now run your rails project

```
rails s
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing sqlite3.
Run the command

```
sudo apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

Then modify gemfile to

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.11'
```

Then run

```
bundle install
```

In rails some packages needs to be installed in your local ,after which they can be included in your gemfile. The same applies for `mysql` and `psql`.